# Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:fastScrollEnabled' with parameter type boolean on androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I've tried setting an ObservableField or a String value, still doesn't work. If I just set a static true or false value instead of the viewModel reference, it works.

**Layout file:**

```
     <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
                name="viewModel"
                type="app.viewmodel.ViewModel"/>
    </data>
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        app:fastScrollEnabled="@{viewModel.isUserAdmin}"
                        app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
                        app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
                        app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
                        app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
                        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
</layout>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
class AppointmentsViewModel()
{
     val isUserAdmin: Boolean = sharedPreferencesRepo.isUserAdmin
}
```

Comment: If the androidx `RecyclerView` is still the same as the old support library `RecyclerView`, last I checked, there is no public method to set fast-scrolling. It's done only in the constructor, with a private method, from the XML attributes.

Comment: Well that's what I'm doing, I'm setting it in XML. Static values work, databinding vales don't.

Comment: Nope, you're not, really. The data binding library is generating code that's basically just calling methods for you. It can't find a public method for `fastScrollEnabled`, so you get that error.

Comment: Damn, you're right. Forgot the internal workings of databinding. So if you'd like to change this based on an external rule(excluding databinding) it's just not possible?

Comment: Thanks for the input. You can provide an answer to this question for others to see as well, if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RecyclerView` currently has no public method for setting the fast-scrolling attributes from code. As of this writing, the only way to enable fast-scrolling is by setting the relevant attributes in the layout XML. `RecyclerView` then calls a private method from its constructor to set that up.

The data binding library, while generating its adapter code, can't find a public method for the `fastScrollEnabled` attribute, which is why you're getting that error. It's just not possible yet.

There is [a request in the Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77988978) to add the relevant functionality to `RecyclerView`, and even [a comment there that points out the data binding limitation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77988978#comment7), but it doesn't seem to be a high priority, at the moment.

---

If you don't mind a little extra work, we can actually accomplish this manually, since `RecyclerView`'s `FastScroller` implementation is simply an `ItemDecoration` and `OnItemTouchListener`. We can copy that class from the library source and set it up externally, allowing us to enable and disable fast-scrolling programmatically, and thusly handle it through data binding.

Directly copying [the current `FastScroller` class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/baaf6845487edfe94fb470730d35f1f9cfbae190/recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/FastScroller.java) should require only a few minor edits that will be obvious (e.g., changing the `package`, some annotations, etc.), and the following example assumes that you have it copied under its original name, `FastScroller`.

There is one vital addition necessary to allow detaching a `FastScroller` from its `RecyclerView` without error. (Indeed, it seems possibly oversight that it's not there already.) In `FastScroller`'s `destroyCallbacks()` method, add a call to `mShowHideAnimator.cancel()`:

```java
private void destroyCallbacks() {
    mRecyclerView.removeItemDecoration(this);
    mRecyclerView.removeOnItemTouchListener(this);
    mRecyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(mOnScrollListener);
    cancelHide();

    // ADD THIS
    mShowHideAnimator.cancel();
}
```

Fortunately, a `FastScroller` basically requires no further attention after instantiation, and since this is replacing a `RecyclerView`-internal functionality anyway, it makes sense to attach each `FastScroller` instance to its `RecyclerView` as a tag, so we don't have to track those instances anywhere else. We only need to be able to retrieve them once later to detach, and this arrangement works well with the data binding setup.

We need to define a unique resource ID as our tag key. It can be placed in any resource file under the `res/values/` folder; `/res/values/ids.xml` would be appropriate, if you like things neat.

```xml
<resources>
    <id name="recycler_view_fast_scroller_tag_key" />
</resources>
```

Our `FastScroller` initialization code<sup>1</sup> is essentially a reordering of the initializations in `RecyclerView` and its constructor, consolidated in a `static` utility method:

```java
static void initFastScroller(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    Resources resources = recyclerView.getContext().getResources();
    Resources.Theme theme = recyclerView.getContext().getTheme();

    StateListDrawable verticalThumbDrawable = (StateListDrawable)
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.thumb_drawable, theme);
    Drawable verticalTrackDrawable =
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.line_drawable, theme);
    StateListDrawable horizontalThumbDrawable = (StateListDrawable)
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.thumb_drawable, theme);
    Drawable horizontalTrackDrawable =
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.line_drawable, theme);

    if (verticalThumbDrawable == null || verticalTrackDrawable == null
            || horizontalThumbDrawable == null || horizontalTrackDrawable == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Trying to set fast scroller without all required drawables.");
    }

    FastScroller fastScroller =
            new FastScroller(recyclerView, verticalThumbDrawable, verticalTrackDrawable,
                    horizontalThumbDrawable, horizontalTrackDrawable,
                    resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fastscroll_default_thickness),
                    resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fastscroll_minimum_range),
                    resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.fastscroll_margin));

    recyclerView.setTag(R.id.recycler_view_fast_scroller_tag_key, fastScroller);
}
```

This example moves all of the specific resource selections into the `initFastScroller()` method for simplicity, but this all can certainly be modified and rearranged however is needed; e.g., into a custom `RecyclerView` subclass. Additionally, you can specify whatever dimension arguments you like here, though the example is using the default resource values from the `RecyclerView` package.<sup>2</sup>

The drawables are being handled dynamically now, so their corresponding attribute settings need to be removed from the layout XML:<sup>3</sup>

```xml
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:fastScrollEnabled="@{viewModel.isUserAdmin}"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

Lastly, to tie all of this together, the `setFastScrollEnabled()` method shows how we can enable and disable fast-scrolling programmatically, and we annotate it as a `BindingAdapter` to expose that functionality to data binding through the `fastScrollEnabled` attribute:

```java
@BindingAdapter("fastScrollEnabled")
public static void setFastScrollEnabled(RecyclerView recyclerView, boolean setEnabled) {
    Object fastScroller = recyclerView.getTag(R.id.recycler_view_fast_scroller_tag_key);
    boolean isEnabled = fastScroller instanceof FastScroller;
    if (setEnabled != isEnabled) {
        if (setEnabled) {
            initFastScroller(recyclerView);
        } else {
            // Detach the FastScroller from the RecyclerView
            ((FastScroller) fastScroller).attachToRecyclerView(null);
            // Nullify our only reference to it
            recyclerView.setTag(R.id.recycler_view_fast_scroller_tag_key, null);
        }
    }
}
```

This method first checks for our `FastScroller` tag on the `RecyclerView` at `R.id.recycler_view_fast_scroller_tag_key`. If it's there, then fast-scrolling is currently enabled, and disabled otherwise. If that state is different than what we've been called to set, continue either to initialize and `setTag()` the `FastScroller` (which handles attaching itself to the `RecyclerView` internally upon instantiation), or to detach it and nullify the tag.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> These methods are provided in Java solely because that is the language of the code borrowed from the original sources. If you would rather have it in Kotlin, Android Studio can auto-convert it rather adequately as a first step, though you may wish to make further syntax/structural/etc. adjustments.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> The given three `R.dimen`s all resolved and built without issue in my tests, somewhat unexpectedly. If you do want to use those default values but have problems doing so, you can copy the corresponding [`<dimen>`s from the library source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/baaf6845487edfe94fb470730d35f1f9cfbae190/recyclerview/recyclerview/res/values/dimens.xml) as well.</sup>

<sup><sup>3</sup> This should work with or without the `app` namespace prefix on the `fastScrollEnabled` attribute, since it's apparently ignored/stripped by the data binding framework. It is left in the XML here only to show the minimal changes necessary.</sup>

---

Of course, this all works independently of data binding, as well, and it can be adapted into more suitable utility methods, or Kotlin extensions, for example:

```kotlin
var RecyclerView.isFastScrollEnabled: Boolean
    get() = getTag(R.id.recycler_view_fast_scroller_tag_key) is FastScroller
    set(value) {
        if (value != isFastScrollEnabled) {
            if (value) {
                // Convert initFastScroller() from above as you like
                initFastScroller(this)
            } else {
                // Detach the FastScroller from the RecyclerView
                (getTag(R.id.recycler_view_fast_scroller_tag_key) as FastScroller)
                    .attachToRecyclerView(null)
                // Nullify our only reference to it
                setTag(R.id.recycler_view_fast_scroller_tag_key, null)
            }
        }
    }
```